# Detached entity passed to persist in Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have created a Spring MVC converter, to handle entity mapping: (sorry, the piece of code is in Kotlin, shouldn't be hard to understand)

```
class BaseEntityConverterFactory(val em: EntityManager) : ConverterFactory<String, BaseEntity?> {

    override fun <T : BaseEntity?> getConverter(targetType: Class<T>)
            = BaseEntityConverter(targetType) as Converter<String, T>

    private inner class BaseEntityConverter internal constructor(private val baseEntityClass: Class<*>) : Converter<String, BaseEntity?> {
        override fun convert(source: String): BaseEntity? {
            if (source.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            } else {
                return em.find(baseEntityClass, source) as BaseEntity? ?: throw EntityNotFoundException("Entity $baseEntityClass with $source was not found.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is great and it works:

```
@GetMapping @Transactional
fun myEndPoint(@RequestParam entity: MyEntity) {
    ...
    em.persist(entity)
}
```

Like this, I get the correct entity directly in the method. The problem is that the entity is `detached` and `em.persist` leads to `detached entity passed to persist`.

Of course I can call `em.merge` before, but I would prefer to load the entity as `attached`. Is this feasible?

**EDIT** It seems that calling `em.merge` doesn't help. The entity is still in detached state. I guess there must be something done within the `ConverterFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have initialized your entities in web scope (which actually should not know details of your persistence layer implementation), and then passed to  service layer, which might be using different thread...

you should apply long-living "OpenSessionInView" pattern, which now considered as "bad practice", or "antipattern".  This pattern will assure that your entities will use same session instance, from the very beginning of your web request, till the web request sent all response data.

Or another option: rework your application   introducing pure DTO layer, and creating mapping. DTO is processed in WEB layer, and passed to Service layer, where it is mapped to entity. In this case I would suggest to use Mapstruct for mappers generation

UPDATE:

You have your 2 entities.

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    // ...properties
    @Id
    private Long id; 
    String stringProperty;
    LocalDate dateProperty;
}

@Entity
class MyDependentEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=MyEntity.class)
    MyEntity entity;

    // ... properties
}
```

Now you want your service to make it possible to update your `MyEntity` and your `MyDependentEntity`

For this purposes you create DTO's, which will be pure representation of your entities:

```
class MyEntityDTO {
    Long id; 
    String stringProperty;
    LocalDate dateProperty;
}


class MyDependentEntityDTO {
    Long id;
    // here we will be transferring the ID of the entity.  Or we can pass the DTO. 
    // it depends on usage scenario. 
    Long entity;
}
```

For this updates you create service layer, which in place will be using this DTO.   Or I call those "Usermodel" object, i.e. datamodel which is open for clients of my service/app/microservice/you-name-it.

```
@Service
class ManagementService {
    MyEntityRepository entityRepository;
    MyDependentEntityRepository dependentEntityRepository;

    MapStructMapper mapper;

    @Transactional 
    public MyEntityDTO saveOrUpdate(@Valid MyEntityDTO dto) {
         MyEntity managedEntity = Optional.ofNullable(dto.id).map(entityRepository::findOne).orElse(new MyEntity()); 
         // now we need to copy values from dto to managed entity. We can write set of setters by own hands, or use the [mapstruct][1]
         mapper.map(dto, managedEntity);
         managedEntity = entityRepository.saveAndFlush(managedEntity);

         return mapper.map(managedEntity); 
    }


    @Transactional 
    MyDependentEntityDTO saveOrUpdate(MyDependentEntityDTO dto) { 
         // first of all we assume, that if there is no passed id, the entity should be created 
         // and if it is present the entity, already exists.
         MyDependentEntity managedEntity = 
         Optional.ofNullable(dto.id).map(dependentEntityRepository::findOne)
              .orElse(new MyDependentEntity()); 
         // it is up to you which logic to apply if ID exist, but no entity found.     
         // Current implementation will throw nullpointer exception in this case. Which for me is quite fine. 
         // now we need to copy values from dto to managed entity. We can write set of setters by own hands, or use the [mapstruct][1]
         mapper.map(dto, managedEntity);
         managedEntity = dependentEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(managedEntity);

         return mapper.map(managedEntity); 
    }
}
```

Now to the mappers.  you can create it by your own. But that will require lots of  monkeycoding, and that might become a place for problems, when you update your entity and dto, but forgot to update your mapper.   Mapstruct comes here, and gives a greate support. It is annotation processor, which allows to generate the boilerplate code.  you simply write:

```
// componentModel="spring" will make the generated MapStructMapperImpl class 
// into a spring bean, available for injection in your services. 
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
abstract class MapStructMapper {

     @Autowired
     MyEntityRepository entityRepository;

     abstract MyEntityDTO map(MyEntity entity);
     // MappingTarget annotation marks the destination  object. 
     abstract void map(MyEntityDTO dto, @MappingTarget MyEntity entity);

     abstract MyDependentEntityDTO map(MyDependentEntity entity);   
     abstract void map(MyDependentEntityDTO dto, @MappingTarget MyDependentEntity entity); 


     //  This method will be picked up by mapstruct automatically to 
     //  map your Long property to MyEntity, during mapping of MyDependentEntity.
     //  NOTE: here you have to chose how to deal with NULL values. 
     // Mapstruct does not imply any rule: you write custom mapping on your own. 
     MyEntity mapMyEntityFromId(Long id) {
          return Optional.ofNullable(id).map(entityRepository::findOne).orElse(null); 
     }
}
```

With described approach you can create your Web tier easily and decouple the storage implementation, and web logic.

For example: if you replace SQL with JPA to   MongoDB. you will not need to rewrite the  web tier at all. Just to rework your repositories, making those MongoDB Repositories.    service layer in this case and mapping service should not be recreated.... NICE :)

Comment: Can you be more specific with the second option? Could you give some example of such thing?